# Android 10: select different voice input language than primary language

Tags: android

On a (Samsung) phone with Android 10 and OneUI2.1, I can't use the voice input in Google apps (Maps, keyboard, etc) with other than the primary language.

I'd like to keep using English as the primary language on the phone, but for voice search on Maps I'd prefer the local (non-english) one.

If I change the primary language to the local one, everything works (including search by voice), but after changing back to English as primary language even though selecting my local language for `Google Voice Typing`, it defaults back to English when I open the search:

[image]

Is this intended, or I'm missing something? How can I use the local language in Google's applications when the phone's primary language is in English?

(Note: Waze can use the local language as voice input, but I think it does not use Google's voice typing keyboard)

Answer (score 1):

try this code :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                    RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Need to speak");
```

Comment: I'm looking for a basic android solution (i.e. without programming), do you have something for that?